# Kubernetes Ingress Service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am facing one issue in kubernetes, I have setup kubernetes like:-
One HA proxy server
Three Masters servers
Two workers

When I deployed the pod, it works fine with ip:portnumber 
But when I use the ingress service and point to 80 port with domain url. Than I am getting the error. I have created the record in cloudflare with my Worker IP Address.

Before that I have setup the environment with:- 
One Master and two workers, In that case its working fine. But don't understand why I am getting error in new environment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUuvl.png)

Comment: impossible to tell what is wrong when you do not disclose your k8s resources configuration. we would need pod\service\ingress resource configuration. how did you setup ingress (not ingress resource)?

Comment: I have resolved the issue, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Can you please share in an Answer how you resolved it so other may benefit from that ? Thanks.